# boost ptr_vector: transfer the ownership of all the allocated objects

Tags: c++, boost

Does the ptr_vector release ownership of the contained objects when it is passed as an argument to a function?

```
class MyClass {
    void MyClass::consume(ptr_vector<Object>& objects)
    {        
        boost::swap(objects,objects_);
    }
    ptr_vector<Object> objects_;
};

void foo()
{
ptr_vector<Object> objects;
objects.push_back( new Object() );

     MyClass myClass;
     myClass.consume(objects);
 }
```

I want to be able to:

1. Store a list of heap allocated objects on a list.
2. Pass the list to MyClass. MyClass then takes ownership of this list, stores it in a member.
3. After MyClass::consume returns, the caller no longer has access to the objects.

I am not sure whether ptr_vector is the suitable container.

Comment: I suppose it has the `swap` method? - I don't see how you could "consume" an immutable vector, though.

Comment: `ptr_vector<Object> objects();` is a function declaration. Please try compiling a code before posting. Don't make us first correcting your code, then answer the question.

Comment: @UncleBens your suggestion did the job.  If you want to post an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Nawaz: I corrected all the errors and updated the code to use UncleBens' suggestion.

Comment: @CandyChiu: What is `pointers` in the function? Did you compile it?